# Assigning ID to Objects transmitted in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects and I want to pass them into a XML file. The Ojects lack of an attribute ID, in fact the form of the array is:

```
var people = new[]{
new {Name="James", Age="22", Company="FF"},
new {Name="Susan", Age="31", Company="PK"},
new {Name="Peter", Age="24", Company="TF"},
}
```

Is there any way to pass them in an xml file, granting to each one of them an ID starting from 1 and increased by 1 for each Object?

The desired form of the xml elemnts should look like:

```
<People>
<Person ID="1">
<Name>James</Name>
<Age>22</Age>
<Company>FF</Company>
....

</People>
```

It would be ideal if the solution would constist of one only LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = new XDocument(
                 new XElement("People",
                     people.Select((p, i) =>
                         new XElement("Person",
                             new XAttribute("ID", i + 1),
                             new XElement("Name", p.Name),
                             new XElement("Age", p.Age),
                             new XElement("Company", p.Company)
                         )
                     )
                 )
             );
```